# Why CSS is not applied on image on page load and it cause CLS problem?

Tags: html, css, cumulative-layout-shift

On the website that I'm working on (https://obkio.com/) we have a CLS problem on the homepage. The background image of the top blue section should take the full width of the screen but on load it doesn't for few seconds. We see right and left margins (the problem is more visible if you throttle your network speed to 'Slow 3G').

It looks like the image is loaded before the css is applied on it.

I wonder how to fix the problem. I already tried to add style directly in my HTML but it did not work.

like that:

```
<img ... style="width: 100%; object-fit: cover;" />
```

Comment: Honestly I'm not seeing issue you described, but in my experience, including a style tag in the head with the css for content visible on load _seemed_ to help with cls. But its not a foolproof solution as with anything related to web metrics.

Comment: We found a solution. We replace the img tag with a div and add a background-image to the div in css